# Made a socket in C++ in winsock and connected to google and am getting some garbage at the end of the response

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winsock, winsock2

I made a simple web browser and I'm able to connect to Google on the page `www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl` and I get all the http information like `Cache-Control:`, `Content-Type:` etc but the last part after that stuff comes out as garbage, here's what it gives me:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 03:38:22 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bi
n/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: gws
Content-Length: 14534
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1439955502:LM=1439955502:V=1:S=juTG
4tnW5tH5E6BF; expires=Fri, 18-Aug-2017 03:38:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=70=glka-fZspN0pbH8M2m0Oay-dXvaHNwyMqKB-O4dn7ZgObHTbnn7dyc4cfn_uX
XKOobdvfpksNRCV5uM1QWPGXV_MjfxdvW2aQQ4zrEtfdxnZ4IxuPQFM61B_ZI0wDTsJ; expires=Thu
, 18-Feb-2016 03:38:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

▼ï
Bytes received: 3316
From server: ⁿh╖6Ü╗ú»╠╟²ú}╪φ▼²h▌<¢Füg┴½ó┬k■Θµ¢←┤┼
ƒz~ßD╓$╕lw[²▬⌡G¢╕*r|!╩╓⌂╫ñäk┬ÿ.─E▬ÿ≈╨▓ W@D╠y√┐☺àY{J╙Z"╞ëf±4▄aeP↨⌐"╔S¡²C╟╜,?⌠╢|║┤
ÿ√╢φûΓå-╔╖n¢<╞3|(₧&-╖ë>aJVz╛ÖF┌§Θº`á╙⌠≤mlk·ñu
╞?╧m▄û¢ú┘♣âúΘéö>◄╣Θ╝░që└â₧ƒ┼▓┐l·Äu╛▀û½^Ä│⌠kΩò²╔╗ú▼m`Ä ⁿh▼=nπ±@╣╝²²?Γå▒æ~╒ⁿ╟Å]ΦF‼
╚╒R╒Öêß^╧╪O7ΣB?ºß∩φl█.âq)≈«(R→τå┌&«DZ¡(╘╬α◄╗ív:Fñk!}8Ü ┐╬♂E.♥k╘Q$ƒ§%
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 12000
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

namespace Globals{
    extern string input = "";
}
using namespace Globals;

int sck() {
    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    char name[500] = "";
    char ipADDRESS[500] = "";
    char sPORT[500] = "";

    sockaddr_in sName;
    int sNameSize =  sizeof(sName);

    char const* sendbuf = "GET /?gws_rd=ssl  HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: www.google.com:80\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
    "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n"
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
    "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
    "DNT: 1"
    "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;                                    //23.214.132.132 GoDaddy.com
    int WSAERROR = WSAGetLastError();                                   
    //system("color 04");                                               
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.

    printf("IP ADDRESS: 74.125.196.191 is Google \n");
    cin >> ipADDRESS;
    printf("PORT: \n");
    cin >> sPORT;
    u_short PORT = strtoul(sPORT, NULL, 0);
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipADDRESS);                            
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        printf("Unable to connect to server: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    //Get local host name
    iResult = gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Host Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Could not resolve host name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    //------------------------
    //Get peer name
    iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Peer Name: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sName.sin_addr));
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Could not get peer name: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());

    //-------------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);

    //-----------------------------
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult); //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("From server: %s\n", recvbuf);
        }
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else if (WSAERROR == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            printf("recv failed: WSAETIMEDOUT\n");
    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
        sck();
}
```

Comment: The content is gzip-compressed, as advertised by `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

Comment: When you've solved that, you're not using the count returned by `recv()`. It should be `printf("From server: %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Accept-Encoding` header you have sent tells the server that you can accept gzip and deflate encodings, which means that you have to look for the `Content-Encoding` header and decode the content accordingly.

In this case the content has been gzipped, so you would need to decompress it before printing it.

The simplest solution is to remove the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: Does taking out gzip encoding sacrifice performance or some other kind of functionality?

Comment: It just means a little more internet traffic.